# Best way to share code across several setup.py scripts?

Tags: python, setuptools

I've got several packages I'm working on, and I'd like to share code between their setup.py scripts.  Is there any good way to do this or is code duplication my only option?

Comment: As standalone packages, they would have to be able to refer that shared code... You can create a dependency on this shared code in your packages, forcing the user (or package manager) to install the dependencies first, or otherwise duplicate it internally in each package. For local, internal packages, you can play around with arbitrary imports, but it's hackish at best.

Comment: @Nisan.H: Actually, you can instruct installers to fetch setup dependencies, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Normally `setup.py` is the entry point for distribution of distinct packages. As such, it's hard to then share code between those packages.

If you use [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (or it's fork, [`distribute`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/)) in your `setup.py`, you *can* specify packages that must be installed when installing your package with the `setup_requires` entry.

Unfortunately, your `setup.py` is executed first; as soon as the `setup_requires` line is parsed, the extra packages listed there will be installed locally, but this may be too late for your needs.

The work-around is to create a separate `Distribution` object before you call `setup` which defines the `setup_requires` entries:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.dist.Distribution(dict(setup_requires='yoursharedsetuppackage'))
# `setup_requires` is parsed and acted upon immediately; from here on out
# the yoursharedsetuppackage is installed and importable.

import yoursharedsetuppackage

setup(...)
```

Comment: This solution seems to compile `numpy` if I include it within `setup_requires`. Is there a way to use `pip` to install numpy instead?

Comment: @aaragon: why would you need to have numpy as a *setup* requirement? If you really do, then no, to ensure a setup succeeds it'll be installed first just for the setup. If you can possibly avoid the requirement (by using Python code that doesn't need `numpy` to create the setup), then do so.

Comment: I’m creating a library that’s also used as an application, so for the end users I need a straightforward way to install dependencies. I thought to use the setup.py for this but instead of installing numpy from a binary, it actually builds it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @aaragon: then just use `install_requires`, not `setup_requires`. `setup_requires` is for dependencies you need to use in the setup script *itself*.

Comment: Perhaps you can give me a hand with [this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697117/how-do-i-make-setup-py-play-nice-with-code-thats-both-a-library-and-an-applicat)