# Import egg functionality during setup in a buildout

Tags: python, buildout, egg

The `setup.py` file in a package I maintain, uses code from another package to build extensions:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from mydependence import build_ext
...
setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='1.0.0',
    ...
    setup_requires = [
      'mydependence', # is this being checked properly?
    ],
    ...
    install_requires = [
      'mydependence',
    ],
    ...
    )
```

I would like to build the current package with `zc.buildout`, so I create a simple `buildout.cfg` file like:

```
[buildout]
parts = python
eggs = mypackage

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

Unfortunately that does not work as I expect - as I execute `./bin/buildout` and `setup.py` is read, it complains `mydependence` is not found. When buildout runs my `setup.py`, its `sys.path` has no knowledge of packages installed under the directory `eggs` (except for `setuptools` itself!). Apparently, packages in "eggs" and "develop-eggs" are not included in `./bin/buildout`'s paths while it runs the package's `setup.py`.

The question: how to make that work?

Comment: IIRC `setup_requires` packages are being downloaded and installed temporarily into the extracted package before `setup.py` is run; buildout re-uses `setuptools` directly for that, so I'd have thought it would work..

Comment: It does not seem to work for me as it stands. Would setuptools need to find the package in an index? In my current setup, "mydependence" only exists locally, in a `src` directory (being managed by [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer)). I was expecting that `buildout` would tell setuptools that, maybe, some eggs are already around.

Comment: Ah, right, that's an important distinction. `setuptools` acts on it's own and ignores the buildout resources for these, I'm afraid.

Comment: That of course requires I package `mydependence` before testing it, which is not very convenient. Is there a fix for this? If not, how to go about creating a recipe that can do this?

Comment: There will be a work-around; give me some time to write one up, but I am very low on time at the moment so it may be a little while.

Comment: I had a more in-depth look at this and I see no solution through `zc.recipe.egg`/`zc.buildout`. The problem: the recipe `zc.recipe.egg:develop` does not allow space or provide a workaround for reading the ``setup_requires`` entry of a package. You can check it out reading [its source code here](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/src/zc/buildout/easy_install.py), jump to line 827. There you will see buildout write s a "wrapper" `setup.py` that is used for the setup of your package. This `setup.py` file has 2 paths and **only** 2: one for the recipe and one for setuptools.

Comment: That's what I was saying; there is no support for `install_requires` in buildout itself, it'd require some custom handling.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12061891/100297) help at all? Not sure if it'll reuse the local package in your buildout though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that you're already importing from `mydependence` before you're calling the `setup()` method. I can see no way in which setuptools (or buildout for that matter) can ignore the `ImportError` you will get.

If I look at some example code from, for instance, http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/examples.html I see code like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    app=["MyApplication.py"],
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

Note that there's no import of `py2app`. So `setup_requires` apparently is a way to load "extensions" to the basic setuptools functionality. It is not a way to circumvent basic python import errors.

**Update:** see comment below by @MartijnPieters who has a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061891/27401 .

Martijn's example would look like this in your case:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.dist.Distribution(dict(setup_requires='mydependence'))
# `setup_requires` is parsed and acted upon immediately; 
# from here on out the package `mydependence` is installed
# and importable.

from mydependence import build_ext

setup(
    ...
    install_requires = [
      'mydependence',
    ],
    ....
    )
```

Comment: You know, I didn't properly read the OP code? But there *is* a way around this; `setup.py` does inspect and install `setup_requires` but you cannot do the import at the top. Cannot right now fully recall how you then *can* import the installed dependency later on in setup.py, but I've seen it done.

Comment: Ah, quick google leads to: [Best way to share code across several setup.py scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12060925)

Comment: Nice trick, @MartijnPieters! I've updated my answer, pointing at yours.

Comment: Would you believe me if I said I didn't even realize that that answer was mine? I didn't look at the author, just had a vague recollection I had solved this before.. :-P

Comment: With your stackoverflow score, I *can* believe you :-)