# Using code from a dependency in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a little web framework, let's call it Bread, which is used to
build applications like Jam, Marmalade, PeanutButter, and other
toppings. Bread both *builds* and *serves* these applications.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the applications' `setup.py`s
work, given the following requirements:

- The apps depend upon Bread, via
  [setuptool's install_requires](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#declaring-dependencies)
- To build an application at development time, Bread reads some config
  and then emits assets (HTML, JS, CSS, images, etc) to the
  application's `output` directory. In other words, `bread devserver`
  reads `Jam/bread.yaml` and assembles assets in `Jam/output`, then
  serves the application (via Flask, but that's not otherwise pertinent).
- In order to build a *deployable* Jam application, I want to invoke
  Bread during `python setup.py install` of Jam, to build
  `Jam/output`. In production, Jam should not need to build anything.
- I've defined a custom `bdist_egg` setup command where
  `initialize_options` imports Bread, invokes the builder, then sets
  `self.distribution.data_files` with the appropriate tuples, before
  calling the base class. (And *that* was no fun to figure out.)
- Right now, the `bdist_egg` is defined in Jam's `setup.py`. I want to
  move this and other boilerplate code into `bread.setup`, so that I
  can reuse it in Marmalade, PeanutButter, etc.
- Potentially, this means that I'm now importing Bread code before
  Bread has been installed. This will surely arise in a clean install,
  such as a fresh virtualenv on a build machine.

Can this be done with Distutils / setuptools /  Distribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question in [Distutils-SIG](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2013-May/020963.html).
A mention there of `setup_requires` led me to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061891/6364, which gave me the hint
I needed: create a separate `Distribution` object before calling `setup`
which defines the `setup_requires` entries.

Jam's `setup.py` now looks like:

```python
from setuptools import setup, dist

dist.Distribution(dict(setup_requires='Bread'))

from bread.setup_topping import *

setup(
    name='Jam',
    version='0.2',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    **topping_setup_options
)

# Remove *.egg left by bootstrapping Bread
cleanup_bread_bootstrap()
```

---

EDIT: a better explanation of what's happening in Jam's `setup.py` is needed:

- The initial `Distribution(setup_requires='Bread')` is using `easy_install`
  to install Bread and its dependencies in the *current directory*.
- The call to `setup()` triggers the `bdist_egg` below, which uses Bread
  to build Jam's `output`. Bread is found in the current directory.
- `setup()` later installs Jam, Bread, and all the dependencies,
  in the correct location.
- The call to `cleanup_bread_bootstrap()` removes all the Eggs that were
  laid in the current directory by the initial `Distribution`.

---

And `bread/setup_topping.py` looks like:

```python
from setuptools.command.bdist_egg import bdist_egg as _bdist_egg
import os, fnmatch, glob, shutil

def recursive_data_files(treeroot, pattern):
    results = []
    for base, dirs, files in os.walk(treeroot):
        goodfiles = fnmatch.filter(files, pattern)
        if goodfiles:
            results.append((base, [os.path.join(base, f) for f in goodfiles]))
    return results

def make_data_files(output='output'):
    return (
        [('', ['bread.yaml'])]
        + recursive_data_files(output, '*')
    )

class bdist_egg(_bdist_egg):
    def initialize_options(self):
        bake_bread()    # build files to './output'
        self.distribution.data_files = make_data_files()
        _bdist_egg.initialize_options(self)

topping_setup_options = dict(
    cmdclass={
        'bdist_egg': bdist_egg,
    },
    install_requires=[
        'Bread',
    ],
    zip_safe=False,
)

def cleanup_bread_bootstrap(root='.'):
    for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root), '*.egg')):
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            shutil.rmtree(f)  # Egg directory
        else:
            os.remove(f)      # Zipped Egg
```

Comment: Side-effects everywhere.  Oy.